# Expected an identifier instead saw '{'

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, jslint, linter

I am using Atom Editor with the linter and linter-jslint packages

I have my first line of code look like this :

`import {WakandaClient} from "wakanda-client";`

And I get this error :

> Expected an identifier instead saw '{'

Would appreciate some feedback on why I am getting this error when my .jslintrc file contains the `"es6":true` parameter.

You can find the link to the github repo issue [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/issues/194)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this come from that the linter-jslint package of atom use an old version of jslint.

I use instead the [linter-jslinter](https://atom.io/packages/linter-jslinter) plugin.

I think that jslint is also still improving the way it handle the es6 features. But with this package I get a better jslint linter.

Comment: I would suggest using eslint, I think it has the best support for es6 features.